# Merging files (cat) in each-folder Unix

Tags: file, unix, merge, cat

Inside my main folder, I have multiple sub-folders and each sub folder contains multiple files. I want to merge these files in every sub-folder.

So I am trying to do something like this:

```
cd ../master-folder

for file in $( find . -name "*.txt" );
do
cat "all the text files in this sub folder" > "name of the subfolder.txt"
rm  "all the previous text files excluding the merged output obviously"
    done
```

Appreciate the help! Thank you.

Comment: Is the order of appending important ?

Comment: try recursive find with -exec. it will take some escaping voodoo but it's probably doable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it like this, if the order of the files doesn't matter :

```
for i in $(find -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d)
do
    find $i -name '*.txt' -type f -exec cat {} >> $i-list.txt \;
    find $i -name '*.txt' -type f -exec rm {} \;
done
```

The first find looks for subdirectories.

The second one appends all subfile's content to a file

The third one deletes the subfiles.

This doesn't work if there are recursive subdirectories. If you want this, remove '-maxdepth  1'

Comment: Will `$i-list` include the path in the name?

Comment: It will contain the directory name plus -list.txt . What do you mean by the path ? Just though about it, if you use the recursive method, the txt file will be in the listed directory's parent

Comment: I meant the directory name, sorry.

Comment: Won't `>>` be interpreted by the shell and not by `find`?

Comment: `>>` is interpreted by find (I'm not sure why though) as it should. The problem comes from a space I've forgotten between `{}` and `\;` on last find. Should be `{} \;`

Comment: @paul Huh, you are right. Must be that it doesn't match the shell's grammar and `find` (at least the GNU flavor in my case) is smart enough to handle it. Neat!

Comment: I think the `>>` is intepreted by bash in fact. find must output all the `cat`s to stdout, and bash then redirects all to the file. A proof is that `find >> $i-list.txt $i -name '*.txt' -type f -exec cat {} \;` works.

Answer (score 2):

Why not visit each directory recursively? Something along the lines of:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                     

shopt -s nullglob # Make failed globs expand to nothing

function visit {
    pushd "$1"
    txts=(*.txt)
    if ((${#txts[@]} > 0))
    then
        cat "${txts[@]}" > "${PWD##*/}.txt"
        rm -f "${txts[@]}"
    fi
    for dir in */
    do
        visit "$dir"
    done
    popd
}

visit /path/to/start/dir
```

Caveat: If you have sym links that create cycles in your directory tree then this is a bad idea.