# Mac OSX Unix Bash Script to cat all files in a folder to one text file, preferrably with a label at the top of the file

Tags: macos, bash, unix, terminal

I would like to in a terminal (open to other ideas though) on a Mac, take the contents of several subdirectories files and put them into one text file, no pattern matching needed, I want every file in every subfolder, with preferably the file name printed at the top of each.

thanks

I am finding a lot of similar questions, such as this [Merging files (cat) in each-folder Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830136/merging-files-cat-in-each-folder-unix)
but am having a hard time getting such a script to work on Mac OSX, because apparently 'find' works a bit different. Not to mention I'm not particulary good with bash scripts to begin with. Any help's appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

```
find dir1 dir2 -type f -print -exec cat {} \; > output.file
```

Or to avoid running one `cat` per file:

```
find dir1 dir2 -type f -exec awk 'FNR==1{print FILENAME};1' {} + > output.file
```

Note that it will skip the empty files. With GNU `awk`, you can work around that by doing:

```
find dir1 dir2 -type f -exec awk 'BEGINFILE{print FILENAME};1' {} + > output.file
```

Also note that if some files don't end in a newline character, the name of the next file will be appended to the end of that non-terminated line.

If you want to indent the content so as to be able to identify the file names more easily:

```
find dir1 dir2 -type f -print -exec paste /dev/null {} \; > output.file
```

Or:

```
find dir1 dir2 -type f -exec awk 'FNR==1{print FILENAME ":"}
                                  {print "\t" $0}' {} + > output.file
```

To have the file name prepended to each line:

```
grep -r '^' dir1 dir2 > output.file
```

(again, there will be no output for empty files)

Answer (score 1):

A basic `find` with a file test works for me...

```
for file in $(find ./); do test -f "$file" && echo "$file" >> /tmp/merged && cat "$file" >> /tmp/merged; done
```

Comment: should copying and pasting that verbatim work? I put it in both directly on the command line and in a bash script file. and it said 
"usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
       find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]
"

Comment: Yeah, `find` with no arguments doesn't work on OS X.  You need to at least do `find .` inside the `$(`...`)`.  Also seems silly to have `find` spit out everything and then use `test -f` instead of just using `find . -type f` in the first place.

Comment: @MarkReed, note that the equivalent of `test -f` is `-xtype f` (which is GNU specific), not `-type f`.